# execute nodejs command from wscript.run in classic asp

Tags: node.js, asp-classic, vbscript, wsh

I'm trying to execute a nodejs command from a vbscript/classic asp page. I'm starting with lessc (less compiler) but need to use other commands too.

nodejs is installed, and I installed lessc in the global namespace (e.g. `npm install -g less`) I can (at the server cmd prompt) issue lessc and it works.

at the server command prompt, I can issue a command that executes lessc, such as:

`lessc D:\webs\player\Layout\less\app.less > D:\webs\player\Layout\less\app.css`

but when I execute it thusly inside vbscript:

```
dim path : path = "D:\webs\player\Layout\less\"
dim shell : shell = server.createobject("WScript.Shell")
dim errCode : errCode = shell.Run("lessc " & path & "\app.less > " & path & "\app.css", 0, true)
response.write errCode
```

then it does nothing. Substituting the command so that it runs CMD ahead of lessc goes one step forward: it creates a zero byte output file (app.css):

```
dim errCode : errCode = shell.Run("CMD /C lessc " & path & "\app.less > " & path & "\app.css", 0, true)
```

So it looks like it's not finding `lessc`, even though it's defined in the path variable; `ECHO %PATH%` at the servers command prompt shows the path where lessc is located. So I tried executing the full path to lessc and even that doesn't seem to work ( no errors, no output ):

```
dim errCode : errCode = shell.Run("CMD /C C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc " & path & "\app.less > " & path & "\app.css", 0, true)
```

.. frustrated now .. I tried piping the output of `lessc` itself to a file, and it outputs a zero byte file. So it's doing *something*, just not executing lessc.

```
call shell.Run("CMD /C C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc > c:\temp\lessc.txt", 0, true)
```

Just how do you get path variables to work in a shell.run anyway? is there a better way to execute a nodejs command server side from in vbscript/classic asp? it's going to be one of those stupid little things I always forget when working with IIS, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, after a day of mucking about, I came across a github project that has a compressed node and less combo as a standalone package, that is easy to execute just using Shell.Run and you don't have to muck about with environment variables at all.

https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows

So, answered my own question.